# How to simplify this double integral with a dirac delta function in it?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

I am having trouble simplifying the following integral 
$$\int_{-\infty}^t\int_{-\infty}^s f(t,\tau)f(s,\xi) \delta (\tau-\xi)d\xi d\tau,$$
given that $t>s$ and where $\delta$ is the [dirac-delta function.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html)

I don't know what the exact requirements for $f$ are so that the following works
$$\int_{-\infty}^tf(t,\tau)\delta(t-\tau)d\tau=\frac{f(t,t)}{2}$$ but I think we can assume that these requirements hold true in this case. My guess at this problem is then that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^t\int_{-\infty}^s f(t,\tau)f(s,\xi) \delta (\tau-\xi)d\xi d\tau = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^t f(t,\tau)f(s,s) d\tau$$
but I am unsure whether this is true. It is just my intuition given that $t>s$ and $\tau$ is integrated up to $t$. I cannot, however, provide a proper argument for this. Any hints on how to simplify this integral are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a preliminary, mathematically speaking expressions like
$$
\int_0^\infty \delta(x) f(x)dx = f(0)/2
$$
don't really make much sense. I'm guessing this probably comes from considering something like
$
\lim_{n} \int_0^\infty f(x) \delta_n(x) dx
$
where all $\delta_n$ are even. But you might as well consider some $\delta_n$ that aren't even, then you could make
$ 
\int_0^\infty \delta(x) dx
$
any number between $0$ and $1$ and still have the determining property
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \delta(x) dx = f(0).
$$

In order to avoid confusion like that I will simply consider

$$
\int_A f(x) d\mu(x) = \chi_A(0) f(0),
$$
so the integral is zero if $0 \not \in A$ and $f(0)$ otherwise. In other words $\mu$ is simply the dirac measure where $\mu(A)$ is $1$ if $0 \in A$ and $0$ if $0 \not \in A$. Given this we can work out that for fixed $s,t, \tau$
$$
h(\tau) = \int_{(-\infty, s)} f(t, \tau) f(s, \tau+\xi) d\mu(\xi)= \left \{ \begin{matrix} f(t,\tau) f(s, \tau) & \tau \in (-\infty, s) \\ 
0 &  \tau \not \in (-\infty,s) \end{matrix} \right.
$$
At last we then have
$$
\int_{(-\infty, t)} h(\tau) d\tau = \int_{(-\infty, s)} f(t,\tau) f(s,\tau) d\tau,
$$
because $t>s$ and where $d\tau$ refers to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Why do you change the limits of integration in $
\int_{(-\infty, t)} h(\tau) d\tau = \int_{(-\infty, s)} f(t,\tau) f(s,\tau) d\tau,
$ from ${(-\infty, t)}$ to $(-\infty, s)$?

Comment: $
\int_{(-\infty, t)} h(\tau) d\tau  = \int_{(-\infty, s)} h(\tau) d\tau+\int_{[s, t)} h(\tau) d\tau
$ but $h(\tau) = 0$ for $\tau \in [s,t)$ so the second term is zero.

Comment: @Demophilus Why does the variable transformation $f(s,\xi)d\mu(\tau-\xi)\to f(s,\tau+\xi)d\mu(\xi)$ not affect the integration domain?